# Error thrown when converting SQL Server to Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having to convert a lot of T-SQL statements this week to Oracle, most I have worked out but I'm still getting stuck on a few. The code below is one of them, I get the error that that the from clause is incorrect, I have tracked it down to this line of code:

```
NewBlc = Sls.CurrentBlc - SUM(NVL(Sls.NewBlc, 0) AS "New Balance",
```

I do not know what the correct format is to fix it. Any help appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    Sls.CustNme AS "Customer Name", 
    Sls.CustAddr AS "Customer Address",
    Sls.CurrentBlc AS "Old Balance", 
    NewBlc = Sls.CurrentBlc - SUM(NVL(Sls.NewBlc, 0) AS "New Balance",
    Tis
FROM 
    Customers, 
    (SELECT  
         c.Name AS CustNme, 
         c.Address AS CustAddr, 
         c.Balance AS CurrentBlc,
         Cis(s.Item, c.Name) AS NewBlc,
         Sis(c.name) AS Tis
     FROM 
         CUST c 
     INNER JOIN 
         Sales o ON c.Name = o.cust 
     INNER JOIN 
         Purchases i on i.OrderNo = o.OrderNo 
     INNER JOIN 
         Contracters s on i.Item = s.Item
     WHERE 
         o.Order_Date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2008', 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) 
                          AND TO_DATE('30-12-2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
     GROUP BY
         c.Name, c.Address, s.Item, c.Balance) Sls
GROUP BY 
    Sls.CustNme, Sls.CustAddr,Sls.CurrentBlc, NewBlc, Tis;
```

Comment: just do this instead `(Sls.CurrentBlc - SUM(NVL(Sls.NewBlc,0)) AS "New Balance"` Is there a reason you are storing the value in NewBlc

Comment: It was stored in NewBlc is MS SQL, I have the job of converting 50 to Oracle so I'm struggling a bit. On the job training

Comment: are you using this variable NewBlc later somewhere? NewBlc = ... statement is not valid in oracle....if you are not using newblc, then you can just replace with what i had suggested

Comment: I've checked the code and its not used any where else, I even took it out of MS SQL and still works. I have only been here 6month so not 100% sure why it was used. I have 10 left to change, so hopefully done by tomorrow

Comment: @cableload: that's not a **variable** - it's just a different way to defining a **column alias** - but that column there *already has* a column alias (`AS "New Balance")` and you cannot have both at the same time

Comment: Then there is no need for that then......have you tried what i had suggested earlier?